# Dictionary inside dictionary as value

Tags: c#, dictionary

I dont how to added dictionary contain multiple items to another dictionary as value

```
Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,double>> mydic=new Dictionary<string,Dictionary<string,double>>
```

Comment: you never added any values to nbdictionary

Comment: I added, modify code

Comment: it seems a reasonable approach. I don't understand your result/expectation difference.

Comment: See also [the other nearly 1000 questions](https://stackoverflow.com/search?q=%5Bc%23%5D+dictionary+multiple+values) on the topic.

Comment: If you need some _specific_ help, feel free to post a new question. But if you do, make sure you post a much better question. One that includes a good [mcve] that reliably reproduces the problem, for one, and which is consistent with your problem description (your description implies `List<double>` is involved, but there's no sign of any list in your code anywhere). Explain what you've tried to do, and what _specifically_ you're having trouble with. See also [ask] for other advice about how to present your question in a clear, answerable way.

Comment: I have 2 dictionary:
first dictionary is Dictionary<string,dictionary<string,double>>
second dictionary is dictionary that use as value in first dictionary
I want:
 one key in dictionary related to another dictionary as value in first dictionary